# How to change the price of a product on the category page?

Tags: category, event-observer, category-products, magento2.4

I am building a module for customer specific pricing. Here is psuedocode for altering the price for a specific product. This works on the product page and through the checkout journey.

```
$_product = $observer->getProduct(); //price = 4.07
$price = $this->_getPrice($customer_id, $_product->getSku()); ///price = 10.01

$_product->setPrice($price);
$_product->setFinalPrice($price);            
//Disable tier pricing.
$_product->setTierPrice([]);
```

This code is in an observer, listening to the `catalog_product_load_after` event.

In order to change the price on the category page I am doing the same code but listening to the events `catalog_product_collection_load_after` and `catalog_block_product_list_collection`.

```
$_collection = $observer->getCollection();
foreach ($_collection as $_product) {
    $price = $this->_getPrice($customer_id, $_product->getSku()); ///price = 10.01
    $_product->setPrice($price);
    $_product->setFinalPrice($price);            
    //Disable tier pricing.
    $_product->setTierPrice([]);
}
```

I've added logging and can see that the new price is being retrieved and set to the product object, but is not persisting to the category page. I **think** it's because the `$_collection` is not passing the product in the `foreach` by reference, so any changes I make to product don't get saved back into the collection.

**How do I make the category page show my updated product price?**

Answer (score 0):

try

create event:-

> path:- Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_collection_load_after">
        <observer name="product_collection" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Product"/>
    </event>
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="set_custom_price_after_add_to_cart" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Product" />
    </event>
</config>
```

create observer:-

> path:- Vendor/Module/Observer/Product.php

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Product implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_productFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $_collection = $observer->getCollection();
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        //Define your Custom price here
        $price = 10.01;
        if ($item){
            // Get parent product if current product is child product
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            //Set custom price
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
        if ($_collection){
            foreach ($_collection as $_product) {
                $_product->setPrice($price);
                $_product->setFinalPrice($price);
                //Disable tier pricing.
                $_product->setTierPrice([]);
            }
        }
        }
}
```